# tikzpicture position

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I am drawing Venn diagrams in a LaTeX article, using the `tikz` package.

The default position of the picture in the text is like this:

[image]

I would like to change it to this (vertical center):

[image]

How?

Comment: There are a lot of answers about this problem but you need to know the term `baseline` to find them. Possible duplicate ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of the environment `tikzpicture` is a box and you can use `baseline` to place  this box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
Venn Diagramm :
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)] 
  \tikzset{venn circle/.style={draw,circle,minimum width=6cm,fill=#1,opacity=0.4}}
  \node [venn circle = red] (A) at (0,0) {$A$};
  \node [venn circle = blue] (B) at (60:4cm) {$B$};
  \node [venn circle = green] (C) at (0:4cm) {$C$};
  \node[left] at (barycentric cs:A=1/2,B=1/2 ) {$A \cap B$}; 
  \node[below] at (barycentric cs:A=1/2,C=1/2 ) {$A \cap C$};   
  \node[right] at (barycentric cs:B=1/2,C=1/2 ) {$B \cap C$};   
  \node[below] at (barycentric cs:A=1/3,B=1/3,C=1/3 ){$A \cap B \cap C$};
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

[image]